# Is this expression "I made a little bit enhancement, could someone give a check" clear and idiomatic?

Tags: meaning

I am reading a textbook and think there could be enhancement somewhere, so I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/430835/257192).

> It seems that page 32 of “MLaPP” is using notation in a confusing way, I made a little bit enhancement, could someone give a check?

Is this expression clear and idiomatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Give a check" is not idiomatic in the context of *verifying* something.

Idiomatic alternatives using the term "check" would include:

> - could someone check my work?
> - could someone check it?
> - could somebody double-check it?

The latter expression "double-check" suggests that it has already been checked, perhaps by yourself, and you are seeking a second opinion.

In AmE, "check" is also a bank-order, an alternate spelling of the BrE *cheque*, so "give a check" could be idiomatically used in that context, but in your example is not idiomatic and could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is not clear or idiomatic.  It relies on cultural sayings that are not universal in English.

For example, in my culture, it sounds like you just asked for payment for your improvement, when (due to my experience) I'm pretty sure you meant "could someone verify my work?"

Now, I would state that "Can someone double-check it?" would be clear and idiomatic, as people independently verify work (once for the original writer, once for an independent review), but aren't paid multiple times.